# Prbelom with ckeditor elementes

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am developing a web page that has a textarea. This page required very basic text formatting elements like `Bold`,`Italic`,`Underline`and a `SpellChecker` only. So i using CKEditor, I hava added first three but there is a problem with adding `SpellChecker`. What should i do with my code to make it right, my code is :

```
<form>
    <p>
        <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>

         <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
                toolbar: [
                    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'SpellChecker']
                ]
            });

        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/520dzLhp/3/

Comment: do you mean you need the native spell checker or to use the plugin `SpellChecker` of CKeditor it self?

Comment: SpellChecker of CKeditor

Comment: Is there something i missed or wrong with my code ? @ MaveRick

Comment: It's fine but i still don't know what you mean by "problem with adding spellchecker", do you mean that the button didn't appear? or it appeared but not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways to achieve this target here:

**- Native Browser Spell Checker:**

According to [CKEditor tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_spellcheck)..

`By default, browser native spell check functionality is disabled in the editor.`

if you want to [activate native spell checker](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disableNativeSpellChecker) you have to use the config param:
`config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;`

**- Spell Check As You Type (SCAYT):**

Which is a plugin you can [download it here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/scayt), and include it with your CKEditor plugins

**- Spell Checking in a Dialog Window:**

Another solution (If you don't prefer the browser to send many requests during writing) is to use the plugin `WebSpellChecker` which only check your text when you click the spellcheck button and opens a popup with the results and you can [download it here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wsc)

**Update**
After a very long searching and inspecting...
try this:

`toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Scayt']]`

or this:

```
toolbarGroups: [
                  { name: 'editing',     groups: ['spellchecker' ] },
                  { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles' ] }
                  ]
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer and your knowledge about CKEditor. but problem is that i am not able to add  SpellChecker button on toolbar.

Comment: Thanks it's really working but may i know  from where you know to use `Scayt` at the place of `SpellChecker`, I am asking that because i search a lot but don't find any solution of this problem before asking it here